# Taylor series expansions of f(ax, y + dy)

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm required to do a Taylor series expansion of $f(ax, y+ \delta y)$ where $a$ is a constant and $\delta y$ is an increment of $y$. How would it be done?
This is probably a special case of the multi-variate Taylor series expansion of $f(x+ \delta x, y + \delta y)$, which i know how to do.  i.e.

$ f(x + \delta x, y + \delta y)=f(x,y) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\delta x
                                  + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\delta y
                                  + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\delta x^2
                                  + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}\delta y^2  
                                  + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}\delta x \delta y$

Thank you.

Comment: yes. Just put to zero the "$\delta x$"

Comment: and replace $x$ by $ax$

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but since $\dfrac{\partial}{ \partial x}(f(ax)) = a* f'(ax)$ your taylor series should only change by a factor $a$ every time you derive in $x$.

Comment: You never derive wrt $x$